# Word 2016- With multiple RSCCs, how to delete selection but prevent first section from being deleted in a protected document (VBA)?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a document with multiple `RepeatingSectionItems` .The following code works to delete current selection when the document is protected.  However, I am trying to find out how to prevent the first section from being deleted if it is selected because if I delete the first repeating section, I can't get it back and it messes everything up.

```
Application.ActiveDocument.Unprotect "green"
'
 Set objCC = ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle("General").Item(1)
  objCC.LockContents = False
  objCC.AllowInsertDeleteSection = True
  '
 Dim CC As ContentControl
   If Selection.Information(wdInContentControl) Then
      Set CC = Selection.ParentContentControl
      If Not CC.Type = wdContentControlRepeatingSection Then
         Do Until CC.Type = wdContentControlRepeatingSection
            Set CC = CC.ParentContentControl
         Loop
      End If
      'loop through the repeatingsectionitems to find the one that selection is in
      Dim rsi As RepeatingSectionItem
      For Each rsi In CC.RepeatingSectionItems
         If Selection.Range.InRange(rsi.Range) Then
            rsi.Delete
            Exit For
         End If
      Next rsi
   End If
'
Set objCC = ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle("General").Item(1)
  objCC.LockContents = True
  objCC.AllowInsertDeleteSection = False
 '
Application.ActiveDocument.Protect wdAllowOnlyFormFields, Password:="green"
```

Comment: This is very simple to do. Sorry for being blunt, but if you cannot figure this out for yourself after all the help you've already been given you really shouldn't be attempting a project of this nature.

Comment: Have you noticed that when you protect for forms, the content controls become ineditable? That's because traditional Word forms are built to use legacy form fields, not content controls.

Comment: @John Korchok- ah I see.  So you are saying it's better to use legacy forms than content controls when trying to protect documents?

Comment: @ Timothy Rylatt- ah I see. Well I guess I will try to figure it out then. I mean I have to start somewhere.  Trying my best sir.

Comment: If you're using content controls, the appropriate protection is to use read-only with exceptions (protected area exceptions): https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/allow-changes-to-parts-of-a-protected-document-187ed01c-8795-43e1-9fd0-c9fca419dadf

Comment: @JohnKorchok - on Windows in a document protected for forms content controls remain editable, at least they do in O365.

Comment: @MohamadBachrouche - yes everyone has to start somewhere, but you need to start with the basics. What you appear to be attempting is like a non-swimmer trying to swim the Atlantic and learn as they go. Having read all of your questions so far what concerns me is that you do not appear to be picking up the concepts that have already been demonstrated to you. e.g. you have already been shown how to loop through the items in a collection using their index, which is the concept you need to apply here, then only delete if the index is greater than one.

Comment: @Timothy Rylatt- that's fair.  Thank you.  To your point about a non-swimmer trying to swim the Atlantic, since I have unfortunately stranded myself in the middle of the ocean and have been treading water and am about to drown, could you throw me a life ring so I can catch my breath and swim back to shore?  Then I will heed your advice and start with the basics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below loops through the collection of `RepeatingSectionItems` and displays a message box if the index equals one, and only deletes the item if the index is greater than one.

```
'loop through the repeatingsectionitems to find the one that selection is in
Dim index As Long
For index = 1 To cc.RepeatingSectionItems.Count
    If Selection.Range.InRange(cc.RepeatingSectionItems(index).Range) Then
        If index > 1 Then
            cc.RepeatingSectionItems(index).Delete
        Else
            MsgBox Prompt:="You are attempting to delete the first item.", Title:="Unable to Delete Item"
        End If
        Exit For
    End If
Next index
```

Comment: thank you sir for rescuing me.  Can you please point me to an interactive resource for me to start learning basics of vba?  The links you provided in previous questions sent me to the Microsoft website and I have a hard time following those.  Again, sorry for the inconvenience sir.

Comment: @MohamadBachrouche - it’s a very long time since I learned and interactive resources didn’t exist back then. You can learn a lot from the [VBA documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/library-reference/concepts/getting-started-with-vba-in-office#vba-programming-101) as it also covers the basic concepts. Otherwise try asking Google or Bing.

Comment: @TimothyRylatt- ah thank you.  So am I not allowed to post a question again on here until I get more experience?

Comment: @MohamadBachrouche - provided your questions meet the [guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) you can post as much as you like.